# tensorflow serving compile Error :absl lib not defined

Tags: tensorflow-serving, abseil

when i using centos 7 compile tensorflow_serving 2.5.1,something maybe wrong.

I using this command to compile tensorflow_serving：

```
bazel build --color=yes --curses=yes     --verbose_failures     --config=release     --output_filter=DONT_MATCH_ANYTHING  tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server
```

The bazel printed these:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAeqe.jpg)

```
undefined reference to 'absl::lts_2020_09_23::string_view::find(char, unsigned long) const'
```